# What does " 'int' object has no attribute '_getitem_' " mean for my code?

Tags: python, typeerror

I just started Python and as a starter I'm trying to make a calculator (just four functions)
So this is the code:

```
input_start = input("press 1 to perform addition press 2 to perform subtraction press 3 to perform multiplication press 4 to perform division press 5 to quit")
if input_start == 1:
    input_a = input("put your first number here:")
    print input_a
    if int(input_a[0]) == (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0): 
        input_b = input("put your second number here:")
        print input_b
        if int(input_b[0]) == (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0):
            print input_a + input_b
        else:
            print "invalid"
    else:
        print "invalid"
print input_start
```

It's like this for other functions. When I run it, this error comes up:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Baik\Desktop\python projects\calculator.py", line 6, in <module>
    if int(input_a[0]) == (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0):
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What does the error mean and how can I fix this? I know this sounds like I'm asking you guys to fix my code, but I don't know what the error means.

Comment: Have you figured out which line raises the error? It's good practice to indicate this, however obvious it may be. Also shows that you've tried to fix it yourself.

Comment: That comparison won't work at all anyway... A single int is never going to be equal to a tuple of 10 integers.

Comment: why are you using input and not raw_input?

Comment: Thank you all! It's been a great help! Hope you have a great day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_a[0]` equals to `input_a.__getitem__(0)`, here your `input_a` is a `int`, and it don't hava such a method.
I think you are using python2.x, the `input` function will parse the input automaically if it is a number.

```
input_start = input("press 1 to perform addition press 2 to perform subtraction press 3 to perform multiplication press 4 to perform division press 5 to quit")
if input_start == 1:
    input_a = input("put your first number here:")
    print input_a
    if isinstance(input_a, int): 
        input_b = input("put your second number here:")
        print input_b
        if isinstance(input_b, int):
            print input_a + input_b
        else:
            print "invalid"
    else:
        print "invalid"
print input_start
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `input_a[0]` - this tries to get the first index of `input_a`. The square brackets are really short for the `__getitem__` method. However, `input` returns a plain `int`, which doesn't have a `__getitem__` method.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you can't do `[0]` on an integer:

```
>>> 5[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Since you are using `input`, any code that is valid type will be converted automatically. This means that if the user types 5 when you prompt with "put your first number here:", python will take it as the *number* `5`, not the *string* `'5'`.

You also have a lot of other issues, the major one being this line:

```
if int(input_a[0]) == (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
```

This isn't doing what you think it is. I suspect you want to say "if input_a is either 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 0, but what its actually doing is *"if the integer value of the item at index 0 pointed to by the name `input_a` is the same as the tuple `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)`"*

If you want to say is *if the input is between 0 and 9*, so you can do that with:

```
if 0 < input_a < 9:
   # do something
```

If you want to check if the input is a number, you can try converting it:

```
input_a = int(input_a)
```

But this will raise a `ValueError` exception if `input_a` can't be converted into a number, like this:

```
>>> input_a = 'hello'
>>> int(input_a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

Another way to check if input is a number is to use the the `isdigit()` method of *strings*:

```
>>> input_a = '5'
>>> input_a.isdigit()
True
```

Keep in mind that this won't work if the value is already a number, because numbers don't have a `isdigit()` method:

```
>>> input_a = 5
>>> input_a.isdigit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

So, to make your life easy, you need to first convert the input to a string. To do that, replace `input(` with `raw_input(`.

For the rest, as this looks like homework, I leave it up to you.